# Wordpress Docker image error - refused to connect - during plugin details preview

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, iptables

Just noticed that when I click "*View Details*" in my plugins list I get this error:

[image]

I don't see any errors while tailing nginx/php-fpm logs while clicking this link.

Any suggestions on what the culprit can be?

I'm using docker-compose to run MariaDB/Wordpress/Nginx stack.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your `nginx` is configured to send `X-Frame-Options: DENY`. Be sure to set it to `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`, and it should fix the problem. You can do this by adding the option to your `nginx` site configuration:

```
add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
```

Make sure you won't have overlapping `X-Frame-Options` parameters for the same site.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you have set:
Header always set `content-security-policy: frame-ancestors 'none'` in the htaccess file.

This error will occur.